# AWS S3 Ruby url_for response headers (custom file name and file type)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I'm just wondering if this is a bug, an error on my part or has anyone managed to get this working

```
>irb
>require 'aws/s3'
>AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!( 
    :access_key_id    => key,
    :secret_access_key => secret)

>AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(
   filename, 
   bucket, 
   :use_ssl => true,
   :response_content_type=>'text/plain',
   :response-content-disposition=>'attachment; filename=text.txt'
)
```

This will spit out a signed url

I can get a URL out of this but the `:response_content_type` & `:response-content-disposition` options don't seem to do anything at all.

These are documented at
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html#url_for-instance_method

Does anyone have luck with adding these per request headers? Or am I doing it wrong?

**EDIT** I figured it out: If anyone runs into the same - require the right gem not 'aws/s3' its 'aws-sdk' (there are two floating around out there with pretty much the same code - I think the latter is an old version)

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer as well and accept it later on: Following up to your own question is perfectly acceptable, if it had been a real question in the first place, and actually desired, to get it out of the way and make room for new and still unanswered questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aws-s3` is an old version of `aws-sdk`. Lots of code between them just works even if you swap the `require` header. Use `aws-sdk` to fix this problem.

Comment: Actually there is no shared ancestry between aws-s3 and aws-sdk.  That said, they do share a number of interfaces.