# why isn't this AWS rails function url_for setting content-disposition for my request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, content-disposition

i'm using rails 2.3.14 with ruby 1.8.7.  i'm generating authenticated URLs to get S3 objects, and i'm using the latest aws-sdk gem.  i've seen this answer and my code is the same : [AWS S3 Ruby url_for response headers (custom file name and file type)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429050/aws-s3-ruby-url-for-response-headers-custom-file-name-and-file-type)

here's my code.  when i hit the url that this generates, it does not set the content-disposition header in the response, it seems to ignore that option completely.  what am i doing wrong?

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(key, bucket, 
    :authenticated => true, 
    :use_ssl => (ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'),
    :expires_in => S3_EXPIRE_TIME,
    :response_content_disposition => 'attachment;'   # seconds
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the linked post suggests, make sure you are using the [aws-sdk](http://rubygems.org/gems/aws-sdk) gem, not the [aws-s3](http://rubygems.org/gems/aws-s3) gem.